# Firefox vanishes from apps menu unless I remove translations from .desktop file (MATE, non-snap FF)

Tags: firefox, 22.04, .desktop, mate

1. Plain Ubuntu 22.04, removed snap, installed Firefox from Mozilla repository
2. Firefox works well and shows up in apps menu
3. Installed MATE 1.26.0 from the repositories, set it as default desktop
4. Firefox no longer appears in apps list; still runnable from command line
5. `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` is still there
6. I edited it and removed all translations, i.e. `Keyword[langcode]=xxx` -- left only English text `Keyword=xxx`
7. Now it does show up in the menus.
8. My language is `pt_BR`. You can examine the .desktop files (original and edited) in [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5b2zntf5b5peu3r/firefox-problem-mate-2204.zip?dl=1).

Is there a way I can solve this problem without having to change the shipped .desktop file? Is there a limitation of MATE? Some weird character in there that GNOME can deal with and MATE can't?

Comment: You mention repositories but whilst you mention `firefox` came from Mozilla's you didn't provide a link which I feel would be helpful (*I'm aware there is more than one & you didn't specify which though the Mozilla reference may help, but it's used on both*!). You mention adding mate from repositories? but which? how did you add it? what package(s) did you add, as I'm a user of multiple DEs and know how others are added can influence how they run. I didn't notice changing firefox cause issues, but I'm a *dumb aussie* and struggle enough with english (ie. *no language changes are tested*)